# ROS2 Foxy -> Does ros2arduino work?

Tags: arduino, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS2 Community

Currently Im starting on ROS2 development, and planning to use version Foxy.
I want to ask if ROS2 foxy works on Arduino.
The ros2arduino page on git hub says, the newest version of ros2arduino(currently: 0.2.1) is ros2 dashing.
So I wanna ask if somebody has tried it with ros2 foxy.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371724/ros2-foxy--%3E-does-ros2arduino-work-???/) by [Dynamite-wasabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/69940/dynamite-wasabi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure whether this can be of use, as all depends on the hardware you're using.
Anyhows, there exists a software solution called [micro-ROS](https://micro-ros.github.io) aimed at bringing ROS 2 to embedded devices. It [supports Arduino](https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino) and, as you can see, the repo mainline is aligned with Foxy already. Hopefully this helps you!

---

Originally posted by [FraFin](https://answers.ros.org/users/68476/frafin/) with karma: 61 on 2021-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2